# How to smooth an object in this sitution?I can't smooth it

Tags: modeling

[image]

[image]

The wrist looks not smooth enough. so I trying to smooth it with verticle smooth.but it turns to more unsmooth after  verticle smoothing

[image]

And I also tried with sculpt smooth tool but I still not get the result as I expect

how can I do make the waist smooth ?

blender file:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Sh7P0lqkJMQGZYSsexFfER2ifWhOntJN/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could first add topology: In *Sculpt* mode select the *Draw* brush, with a *Strength* of 0 and *Dyntopo* at 12 px. Paint on this part, you won't see anything for the moment as the *Strength* is at 0 but it will add topology nevertheless. Then paint on this part with <kbd>Shift</kbd> in order to smooth:

[image]

Comment: Have to make this answer as best accept answer because it really useful for more people able to see it. I would like dyntopo  and then shirnkwraper. thank you for your answer

Answer (score 4):

Maybe consider subdividing the area with less vertices (edit mode) and then applying the smoothing. I’ve often found this helpful. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Th first thing I notice here is the topology of your mesh, and that is what I think is causing the issue, I'd recommend you to re-topologize the mesh and try smoothing it. Try using the 'remesh' modifier or for more control, softwares like 'Instant Meshes', an open source software that is dedicated to re-topologizing geometry will work great.